# Why a change in seemingly irrelevant code helps kotlin to infer type variables

Tags: generics, kotlin, jjwt

The following code defines a [SigningKeyResolverAdapter](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api/latest/io/jsonwebtoken/SigningKeyResolverAdapter.html) for the [jjwt library](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt)

```
  private val parser = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKeyResolver(object : SigningKeyResolverAdapter() {
        override fun resolveSigningKey(header: JwsHeader<*>, claims: Claims): Key {
            return runBlocking {
                keyRetriever.getPublicKey(header.keyId)
            }
        }
    }).build()
```

The kotlin compilation fails with the following error:

> Cannot infer type parameter T in var !>
>
> JwsHeader.keyId: String! None of the following substitutions
>
> receiver: JwsHeader  arguments: ()
>
> receiver: JwsHeader!>  arguments: () receiver:
>
> JwsHeader  arguments: () receiver:
>
> JwsHeader!>  arguments: () receiver:
>
> JwsHeader!>!>  arguments: () receiver:
>
> JwsHeader!>  arguments: () can
>
> be applied to receiver: JwsHeader<*>  arguments: ()

When the line

> keyRetriever.getPublicKey(header.keyId)

is changed to

> keyRetriever.getPublicKey(header["kid"] as String)

everything works.

I don't get why this change makes a difference. header.keyId also return a string.

Comment: What are the signatures of `keyRetriever.getPublicKey()` and of the operator function `JWSHeader.get()`?

Comment: suspend fun getPublicKey(name: String): PublicKey 
and 
JwsHeader inherits from java Map so it is
 V get(Object key);

Comment: I duplicated your code and created a `getPublicKey` function with the same signature, and there were no compilation errors.